# Oracle sqlplus > substitution a prompt variable

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I have a *.sql script file and there are some `PROMPT` commands in this file which force user to type in something.

I would like to execute this script file with sqlplus and supress the prompt question somehow.

Is there any way to supress the question and substitute its value with a pre-defined variable?

This is my test code:

```
set define on
set define $
SET VERIFY OFF
SET HEADING OFF

DEFINE semaowner = "hello" (CHAR);
accept semaowner prompt "schema owner: "
select '$semaowner' semaowner from dual; 

quit;
```

And the way how I execute it:

```
sqlplus sys/ora123@host:port/schema as sysdba @prompt-demo.sql
```

But it does not work because the prompt appears either the `DEFINE` command is applied or not.

Comment: Why don't you simply comment out the `accept` line?

Comment: If possible we would like to use the exact same script in DEV and PROD environment without any modification. The requirement is that the script needs to ask for info before execute commands in PROD but during development we would like to "mock" these variables and supress prompts.

Comment: There is MS Windows on DEV computers and Unix on PROD (bash).

Comment: Would it be enough to pass an optional command line parameter and have the script default a value if no parameter is passed? That is, you can call it with either `@prompt-demo.sql SOMESCHEMA`, or else just `@prompt-demo.sql`.

Comment: Variables can have default values in DEV but the prompt need to be shown in PROD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could supply the response to the prompt from the command line, wrapped in a  shell script/batch file if necessary:

```
echo schema_name | sqlplus sys/ora123@host:port/schema as sysdba @prompt-demo.sql
```

That works on Windows and Linux.

So you can do that in dev with (presumably) a fixed known value; and in prod just run it as you were before and have to manually enter the value.

You will still *see* the prompt text in dev, but it won't stop and wait for input.

---

If you have multiple prompts you could use multiple echos:

```
(echo schema_name && echo something_else) | sqlplus ...
```

which also works in both; in Linux you could also use a single print statement with embedded newlines:

```
print "schema_name\nsomething_else\n" | sqlplus ...
```

or a heredoc:

```
sqlplus sys/ora123@host:port/schema as sysdba @prompt-demo.sql <<!EOF
schema_name
something_else
!EOF
```

but that doesn't help you on your Windows dev box. (There may be a heredoc equivalent on Windows but I think it's basically rearranging the echos...)

Comment: That works like a charm, thanks. Unfortunately we have more then one prompts in the SQL script file. Can I use your suggested solution in that case as well?